# Grids laying in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, grid, uniformgrid

I want to Display a collection of shapes in a specific way. So, I have a collection of shapes ViewModels, and I want to display it like this :

1) If my collection contains only one shape :

[image]

2) If my collection contains 3 shapes :

[image]

3) if my collection contains more than 3 shapes : (automatically creates a new Row with 3 columns)

[image]

You may say to me "Use UniformGrids", but the problem is that the size of columns is the same ! and I want to have columns with different size ! (depending on the size of elements inside it)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure what you need is to use a WrapPanel.

MSDN Article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Tutorial on how to use it ( wpftutorial ) : http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html

Edit : Follow this interesting link too : [Specifying number of items per row using a WrapPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864792/specifying-number-of-items-per-row-using-a-wrappanel)

Comment: It is customary for users to provide some code example in their answer, rather than just providing one or more links. Please take a look at the [Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page of the StackOverflow help centre for more information.

Comment: I added another link that has some example, I think there is no need now for examples since the SO link already shows perfect code example ( that I don't have enough knowledge to reproduce ). Thanks for the tip, next answer I'll provide will have some examples.